# does ios computed properties increment arc count of any object?

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, swift4.2, computed-properties

I have a code below  and I want to know that does computed properties increment arc count of another object? (retained by arc) For example below
mycustomlabel count is 2 ?

```
var mycustomlabel = UILabel()  
var myc : UILabel {
    get {
        return mycustomlabel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you have a single strong reference at this point.